# Rest Api request in Node js (curl to Node.js, python to Node.js)

Tags: python, node.js, rest, curl, post

I have a curl code block that work succesfully.

```
curl -v -X POST "https://someapihost" \
-d "image_url=someimage.jpg" \
-H "Authorization: form1 key2"
```

And there is a python code block whick work exactly same.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'form1 key2',
}

data = {
  'image_url': 'someimage.jpg'
}

response = requests.post('https://someapihost/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

But I need Node js code block which work samely, so I need to translate these code blocks.

Here is my translation. (I used https://curl.trillworks.com/#node)

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'form1 key2'
};

var dataString = 'image_url=someimage.jpg';

var options = {
    url: 'https://someapihost',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

But the respose.statusCode return 400, so it does not work.
I wonder why this error occur and
 how to currect this code. 
(of course I install request by "npm install request")

I appreciate your reading this question. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the api call you are making, but I would expect the following to work if it expects json as input.

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'form1 key2'
};

var data = {
  image_url: 'someimage.jpg'
}

var options = {
  url: 'https://someapihost',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: data,
  json: true
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```